# What protocol do routers use to determine the host name?

Tags: embedded, ip, nameservers

I am programming an embedded device (at91sam7x, using FreeRTOS and lwIP), which has LAN. When it appears on the router's device list, it has no name. How can I provide one? What protocol do routers use for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DHCP can provide the name of the requesting computer to the server which can then record that against the IP address it gives out.  Many (most?) self-contained router/WiFi boxes will do this and, if not, DD-WRT or OpenWRT will.

Note that the requesting computer must send its hostname in the DHCP request, an optional thing, for this to work.  I don't know if FreeRTOS does this but even it's not an option you could certainly update it to do so.

Some DHCP systems (like the Linux DHCP server) also have the ability to communicate with a DNS server that supports dynamic updates (like Linux "bind") to push the host->ip mapping table to it and thus make the mapping available any device using that DNS server for lookups.

Answer (score 1):

DNS :)

The hostname of this device should be registered on your DNS server.  Which may be your router, otherwise I assume you don't have one yet.

In this case you could for instance set up a Bind server in your network.  Each other device must then use this server as primary DNS server.  The more comfortable solution would be to (also) setup a DHCP server then telling its clients the DNS server's IP.  In fact your router might have a DHCP integrated and allow you to specify a custom DNS server.

Comment: Actually, not always. Many devices will look this up through WINS instead, especially on a home network ;)

Comment: Yup that's right...  I wonder what em0 means with "host name" ;)

Comment: That doesn't even make sense :P

Comment: More specifically, querying the host name associated with a given IP address is called "reverse lookup" (aka "reverse DNS").

Comment: I have no access to router. My question is that how should the device  itself advertise its name, which appears at e.g. in the router's list. Operating systems do that job, but we don't have such in this case.

Comment: What do you mean with "router's list"? Windows can advertise its "Windows Host Name". This is what you see on Windows when you click in Windows Explorer in the left bar on Network. Other than that, other OSs rely solely on DNS.

Comment: Maybe you can add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: dd-wrt for example shows a list of machines on the lan hostname, mac, and ip address.  I am guessing the answer is dhcp not dns...

Comment: The DHCP Server distributes a DNS Server IP to its clients.  The DNS server distributes hostnames to its clients.  So no, DNS is the key. ;)  em0 needs to setup his own DNS server.  (Advertising it via DHCP is great, at least in case he uses DHCP.)

Comment: Maybe the question was not clear, I wanna give a name to my embedded machine, which the router uses then. Same as when you give a name your computer e.g. "BillsNotebook", which name thn appears on router's "known hosts" list. Other answer says, it's a DHCP thing, I'll try it.

Comment: em0: in case you have full root access to the router, you can edit your `/etc/hosts`. Inside it you can add the line `123.123.123.123 BillsNotebook`, in case `BillsNotebook` has the ip `123.123.123.123`. Pro: your router knows that notebook's name. Con: you need to do the same thing on every other computer that should use BillsNotebook instead of 123.123.123.123. That's why DNS was invented, so the DNS server does this work for you. And yes, some DHCP servers have DNS servers integrated, Microsoft's are an example of this.

Comment: em0: but yeah the DHCP will probably work if your DHCP server is powerful enough. Is your hostname set locally? You may check it by entering `echo $HOSTNAME`